# How does session work on web service calls

Tags: web-services, session

Assuming a sends a request twice through REST api. Is it considered as **two different** **session**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST architectural constraints are in general (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)):

> - Client-Server
> - **Stateless**
> - Cacheable
> - Layered system
> - Code on demand (optional)
> - Uniform interface

**Therefore "session" concept is not applicable.** The REST request should contain all data needed to be processed: credentials, resources to use, payload, etc

Comment: What I'm asking is that if the server side creates a session and saves the request information by the client. Will it be different session per call?

Comment: Creating a session is a decision of the server. In a REST service the server should not create a session because it has no data to bound to the client. The session is commonly associated to a web application working with forms. Think in a web-service, the server does not know if it is being executed from a browser, a standalone application or other server. The `session` can not be used

Comment: Yes I know it is improper to do so. but assuming a server did that, will every request be a new session?

Comment: To maintain the session the server needs the client to send a cookie (i.e. JSESSIONID). On a web server that work with sessions, the first request will create a session. In the following requests, since the REST client does not send the cookie, it will create a new one every time